# Minhag to eat Dessert First?

Tags: minhag, food, messiah

A while ago (at least 25 years ago) I recall a friend's mother saying there was a minhag in Tzfat to eat dessert first, because if you had to suddenly stop your meal in the middle because the Moshiach came, you would not have to miss dessert. Now, this friend's mother has a very good sense of humor; and this happened long enough ago that she might have been kidding, but at the time I was too young to realize it. However I figured I would ask if anyone else has heard of this minhag in Tzfat or anywhere else.

Comment: i am very machmir on this one, although I have neevr heard of it. :)

Comment: If the dessert food was milchig but you were having fleishig, it may be a good idea.

Comment: I often do this on Shabbat, my kids love 'backwards dinner" and that way they get to have cake and ice cream as well as chicken. Nothing to do with Moschiach, though

Comment: This is a mistake. Because the order is strength, not kdima bebrachot

Comment: Probably not the only strange thing they do in tzfas

Comment: one must eat dessert first because אין מפטירין אחר הפסח אפיקומן

Comment: I have heard this as well though I haven't seen any source that validates it. What makes this odd to me is in the case of moshiach coming interrupting a meal desert isn't going to seem so important as anything else going on at the moment so why would one need to get it in faster? What if moshiach came right after kiddush before the "desert" anyways?

Comment: @Dude, better yet, what happened if Moshiach came between making a berachah and eating the food ?

Comment: Very interesting. It smacks of the mitzvah of remembering Alma D'atei - the Coming World - and also "From day one (Sunday), remember it (the Sabbath)".

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if that would be considered a minhag - it could be that someone is a glutton or has a sweet tooth so they like fressing dessert before the meal in case Mashiach comes - but that wouldn't be a minhag, it would just be one's personal preference. I don't believe there would be a minhag highlighting the supreme importance of dessert in our lives.

This is only if one would actually think its a minhag, however it was probably said as a joke and/or leitzonus.